# Is there any benefit in-game to getting the special FaceCamo in MGS4 from defeating the Beauties non-lethally?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

When you defeat an unsuited boss non-lethally in MGS4, you get their facecamo pattern.

I know there's an achievement that you can get for getting a whole stack of FaceCamos.  I also know you can get the Solar Gun for defeating their cyber forms non-lethally.
However, what I want to know is whether the Beauty faces have any special interaction with anyone/anything else, or if they have any special function.

Answer (score 1):

In Act 3, the Resistance member will hit on you if you're wearing the Beauty camo, but that's the only real thing it'll do. MGS is not known for much in the way of practical uses for things but it's always been heavy on the subtle jokes.